# MySQL - unique "per FK", nullable column

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Firmware_port_set` (
 `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `firmware_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `address` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `set_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `order_in_firmware` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `firmware_id` (`firmware_id`,`address`),
 KEY `fk_fps_set` (`set_id`),
 KEY `fk_fps_firmware` (`firmware_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_fps_firmware` FOREIGN KEY (`firmware_id`) REFERENCES `Firmware` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_fps_set` FOREIGN KEY (`set_id`) REFERENCES `Port_set_template` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=480 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Where the column `order_in_firmware` is an optional specification of an ordering. If this column is null, the ordering will be done based on the address column instead - basically, the queries are `..ORDER BY COALESCE(order_in_firmware, address)`

Here is an example of the data:

```
Id, firmware_id, address, set_id, order_in_firmware
"461","32","105","13",NULL
"462","32","185","13",NULL
"463","32","265","13",NULL
"464","34","36","14","8"
"465","34","44","14","9"
"466","34","52","14","10"
"467","34","60","14","11"
"468","34","68","14","12"
"469","34","76","14","13"
"470","34","84","14","14"
"471","34","92","14","15"
"472","34","100","15","0"
"473","34","114","15","1"
"474","34","128","15","2"
"475","34","142","15","3"
"476","34","156","15","4"
"477","34","170","15","5"
"478","34","184","15","6"
"479","34","198","15","7"
```

How can I make a constraint that enforces the values of the `order_in_firmware` column to be unique, but only unique "per FK value" (`firmware_id`)  and still nullable at the same time?

Comment: "per FK value" -- Which one? `firmware_id` or `set_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the pair of the "other" column and `order_in_firmware` unique.

```
CREATE TABLE `firmware_port_set`
             (...
              UNIQUE (`firmware_id`,
                      `order_in_firmware`)
              ...)  ...
```

It's not clear from your post which is the "other" column. I assumed `firmware_id`. If that was wrong, you need to change the code accordingly.